# How do I pass a response data I am getting back from createasyncthunk in redux toolkit to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a login component, a verification component and a `userSlice` file which has `createAsyncThunk`.

userSlice.js:

```js
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/login',
  async ({ email, password }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'my_url',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
          }),
        }
      );
      let login_response = await response.json();
      console.log('response login', login_response);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log('success from here')
        // localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
        return login_response;
      } else {
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error', e.response.data);
      thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e.response.data);
    }
    return login_response;
  }
);
```

Here I get a response back when I post data. I have named it as `login_response`.
I simply need to pass it to my verification component.
I searched for it online but I did not understand the solutions which were there.

In my verification component I have imported loginUser like so

```
import { loginUser } from '../features/user/userSlice';
```

I know that loginUser has returned login_response. Now how do I access login_response in the verification component ?

Comment: You are already returning `login_response`, what is the issue? Have you considered the [official docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results)? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] that show where and how you are using this `loginUser` action?

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope its clear now...

Comment: Are you trying to access this returned value in a callback? Or is there a state slice that is handling a `loginUser.fulfilled` action and you need to select some state that is updated? This is the part I was asking for a [mcve] for so we can see what/where/how you are trying to use this `loginUser` action and returned value.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can access it using :

```
// Then, handle actions in your reducers:
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // standard reducer logic, with auto-generated action types per reducer
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    // Add reducers for additional action types here, and handle loading state as needed
    builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      // Add user to the state array
      state.entities.push(action.payload)
    })
  },
})

// Later, dispatch the thunk as needed in the app
dispatch(loginUser(123))
```

according to doc at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk :

**createAsyncThunk** returns a standard Redux thunk action creator. The thunk action creator function will have plain action creators for the pending, fulfilled, and rejected cases attached as nested fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState: {
    userData: []
  },
  reducers: {
    // standard reducer logic, with auto-generated action types per reducer
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    
    builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      // Add user to the state
      state.userData.push(action.payload)
    })
  },
})
```

now you can access it in your verification component

do not forger to export slice and add it to your store

and then in verification component:

```
const user_data = useSelector(state => state.users.userData)
```

console.log it to verify if you are getting right data.